# format date error in Ember JS: could not find property on object

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Uncaught Error:  Handlebars error: Could not find property 'format-date' on object (generated post controller). in ember  js

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown when the handlebars template contains a custom helper that is not registered.

**Example** *(look at the console output)*

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gosegede/1/edit

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

    {{format-date "test"}}

</script>
```